# How do I retrieve the event for an eventMessage

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

The Graph API v1.0 documentation states that the `eventMessage` resource type has a relationship called `event`, which should return

> The event associated with the event message.

Full docs here:

[eventMessage resource type](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/eventmessage)

I would interpret this as the ability to request a resource with a URL such as the following:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<message id>/event`

in the same way that the attachments relationship can be accessed i.e.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<message id>/attachments`

However, this does not appear to work. Instead I get the following error in the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'event'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f3203560-0e35-4575-a34c-2a2a884f551a",
            "date": "2016-07-13T09:58:58"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I sending the wrong request? Is the documentation wrong? Is there a bug?

Hopefully someone can clarify, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for reporting, I'm checking on this and will update soon.

Comment: @JasonJohnston thanks Jason, looking forward to the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can only access the `event` property via the `$expand` parameter in the URL. So you could do something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<message id>/?expand=
Microsoft.Graph.EventMessage/Event
```

Or if you're using the Outlook API endpoint, something like:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/<message id>/?expand=
Microsoft.OutlookServices.EventMessage/Event
```

It is on our roadmap to simplify this, but this is the way it works for now.

Comment: We found the exact syntax was `?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/Event` but otherwise this was massively helpful

Comment: My apologies, I forgot you were using Graph :). I'll update my answer.