# Office 365 - Filter on expanded messages

Tags: odata, office365, office365api

Thanks to [How do I retrieve the event for an eventMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348539/how-do-i-retrieve-the-event-for-an-eventmessage) we've sucessfully retrieve now the events in our inbox on o365.

Now our problem is that we want to show the user only events to which he hasn't responded. We've tried things like:

$expand=Microsoft.OutlookServices.EventMessage/Event($filter=ResponseStatus/Response%20eq%20'NotResponded')

But without success, we still get accepted events. If we try to put it outside in a filter

$filter=Microsoft.OutlookServices.EventMessage/Event/ResponseStatus/Response%20eq%20'NotResponded'

we get an error like "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."

Is there an easy way to achieve that without a filtering inside the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ResponseStatus/Response is marked as not filterable, so this cannot be achieved in this fashion