# Outlook REST API EventMessage Requires All and Shared Constraint Permissions

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

We are using Outlook Mail API to fetch Outlook Mail and Mail with Events by including `Microsoft.OutlookServices.EventMessage/Event` in the **$expand** parameter of Outlook's v2.0 REST API as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575059/482536.

However, some of our users are having trouble fetching messages now, and the error is telling us that Calendar permissions with **All** and **Shared** constraints (e.g. Calendars.ReadWrite.All, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared) are missing. We didn't expect to need these constraints so we didn't include the constraints when requesting permission scopes. I only see the constraints being defined in the [Graph API reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#microsoft-graph-permission-names), but we're using the REST API.

Do we need to request these permissions for all of our users? What's the scenario where not having these permissions will fail?